# How to Reinstall Sound Drivers?

Tags: sound, kubuntu, hardware, 17.10

I'm having some sound issues, and I believe that reinstalling or resetting my sound drivers or sound settings may solve this issue. How can I do this?
This is my list of playback devices from `aplay -l`

> `sarah@ConvergentRefuge:~$ aplay -l
>   **** List of PLAYBACK Hardware Devices ****
>   card 0: HDMI [HDA Intel HDMI], device 3: HDMI 0 [HDMI 0]
>     Subdevices: 1/1
>     Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
>   card 0: HDMI [HDA Intel HDMI], device 7: HDMI 1 [HDMI 1]
>     Subdevices: 1/1
>     Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
>   card 0: HDMI [HDA Intel HDMI], device 8: HDMI 2 [HDMI 2]
>     Subdevices: 1/1
>     Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
>   card 0: HDMI [HDA Intel HDMI], device 9: HDMI 3 [HDMI 3]
>     Subdevices: 1/1
>     Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
>   card 0: HDMI [HDA Intel HDMI], device 10: HDMI 4 [HDMI 4]
>     Subdevices: 1/1
>     Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
>   card 1: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 0: 92HD91BXX Analog [92HD91BXX Analog]
>     Subdevices: 1/1
>     Subdevice #0: subdevice #0`

**EDIT 0:** I tried https://askubuntu.com/a/8773/645874 but no luck. (This includes restarting the system, and not simply logging off)

Answer (score 3):

Try this ( Open terminal: `Ctrl + Alt + T`):

1. **Install pavucontrol**
   `sudo apt-get install pavucontrol`
2. **Install PulseAudio**

   2.1 `sudo apt update`

   2.2 `sudo apt install pulseaudio`

   2.3 Now reboot your computer.

   2.4 Check if **PulseAudio** was installed `pulseaudio --version` , terminal should output something similar to mine

> pulseaudio 11.1

3. Start **AudioPulse** `pulseaudio --start` (this doesn't open the GUI)
4. Open the **Volume Control** GUI `pavucontrol`, this should start something similar to mine

[image: See the Screenshot here]

and from here set to default audio input/out by checking that green checkmark